# PHP MySQL error Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error -1 from storage engine

Tags: php, mysql, crud

Has anyone gotten -1 error running a query against MySQL from a PHP file?

I tried searching for this error but never find a -1 error.

I can't do any queries. I was able to add the tables just fine, but adding rows just doesn't work.

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you using Magento?

Comment: No. No frameworks, straight PHP.

Comment: Without code all that people can tell you is that you have errors

Comment: @Mihai Absolutelty true! I'll add code in a second

Comment: My suspicion is that you do not have the permissions set properly, but we need to see the code you are using to identify the specific issue.

Comment: What operating system are you running your code on?

Comment: It's a Linux box. I think @stubsthewizard may be correct about permissions. I should not work quickly and half asleep. And I'm not on the PC that has the code so I have to wait until I can acces that computer toi post the code. My apologies to all for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, mysql is saying that it tried to access the files, and failed. The storage engine on your machine/server gave mysql the error code '-1'.

It depends on your system as to what this actually means, but it is likely either:

- MySQL doesn't have permission to read/write to a file
- The file MySQL is trying to read doesn't exist
- The disk is full and MySQL can't write any temporary files
- The file MySQL is trying to read is corrupted

Either way, this is an error from the storage engine on your machine, and mysql is just passing it along.

Comment: Thanks @samlev. I'm going to check all those reasons. I think it may be permissions, but it could also be disk space.

Comment: Turns out they admitted to not having proper permissions set. It still isn't fixed, but that was the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if your disk isn't full.

Then use the `CHECK TABLE` and `REPAIR TABLE` statements to check and repair MyISAM tables, because they probably corrupted for some reason..

Comment: Thanks @lxer. Outside of space and permissions, I'll try checking the tables as well.